# If $M$ and $N$ are non-isomorphic simple $R$-modules then $\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(M,N)=0=\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_{n}(M,N)$ for $n \geq 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Let $M$ and $N$ be non-isomorphic simple $R$-modules. I have to show that $\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(M,N)=0=\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_{n}(M,N)$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Since $M$ and $N$ are simple it must be $M \cong R/m$ and $N \cong R/n$ for distinct maximal ideals $m$ and $n$ of $R$. Only thing I could calculate $\mathrm{Tor}^{R}_{1}(R/m,R/n)=(m \cap n)/mn=0$. How can I calculate other objects ?

Comment: For $\mathrm{Ext}$ this should be based on the fact that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)=0$ (a homomorphism between simple $R$-modules is zero or an isomorphism)

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: Yes of course, as the tag suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $R$ is commutative, here's a simple proof : let $x\in n\setminus m$ (it exists because $n\subset m \implies n = m$ and we know $n\neq m$).

Then $x$ acts invertibly on $R/m = M$, but it acts as $0$ on $R/n= N$.

But both $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R$ are $R$-linear functors, so that $\mathrm{Tor}^R_i(M,N)$ is canonically an $R$-module, and multiplication by $r\in R$ on $M$ (or on $N$) induces multiplication by $r$ on $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,N)$ (same for $\mathrm{Ext}$)

Therefore $x$ acts invertibly, and as $0$ on $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,N)$, from which it follows that it's $0$. The same holds for $\mathrm{Ext}$.

Comment: The assumption that $R$ is commutatiove is probably implicit: otherwise, assuming that all the modules are meant as left modules, one has to e.g. specify some bimodule structure on $M$ so that $$\mathrm{Tor}^R_*(M, N)$$ makes even sense.

Comment: @PavelČoupek : you're right, though the question for $\mathrm{Ext}$ still makes sense (and is a reasonable generalization if $\hom$). But I'm not sure it's true for general noncommutative $R$